# Little bug space on Custom Spinner

Tags: android, android-layout

I just make my spinner custom view to dropdown list and it's support. But somehow, a little space appear below the "15" text so it dont make linear horizontally.

[image]

Here is my code :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:background="@drawable/timepickerbutton"
    android:paddingEnd="20dp"
    app:drawableEndCompat="@drawable/ic_arrow_down_sign_to_navigate" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change the height parameter to wrap_content and width to fill_parent

I had next custom spinner item in one of my projects without any other layout behind him, just pure XML file and one TextView and it works as it suppose:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/customSpinnerItemTextView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="5dip"
    android:textColor="@color/vectorColor"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    tools:text="sometext" />
```